# How to wp_redirect on 'init' hook on condition of current post id?

Tags: shortcode, wp-redirect

I have made a shortcode, because we can't redirect page within shortcode using wp_redirect so I used **'init'** hook to check the $_POST/GET parameter and make system redirect. But I'm stuck in a condition checking where I need to check current post id.

The problem is that until 'init' hook **global post** doesn't have any value. So I can't get current post/page id. Now how to handle these type of problem. In shortcode I can't redirect but can get **global post**. On 'init' I can make redirect but can't get current post id or global post variable value.

For now, I can use **$_SERVER** variable to get current URL and passing current url to **url_to_postid** to get current post id. But I don't think this is the proper and good way of doing this. It's like a patch and not full proof solution. I wonder what should be the standard and correct way for doing redirect with getting current post/page id?

Comment: Use the `template_redirect` hook

Comment: Thanks Pieter, this is what I was looking for. Perfect hook. It worked.